# make parent links display active class when sub menu link is selected

Tags: php, html, css

I have a CSS/HTML Menu, when the li class is `active` it shows it as a different colour.

my menu links are stored in a database, so i run SQL Queries to display the menu links.

I am trying to make it so, if a user is on a sub menu page it will display the top link (parent top link) as active.

Whats the best way to do this - i have tried doing an if statement on the top links but this doesnt work if a sub menu link is selected

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
<li <?php if($_GET["id"] == '') { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="/home.php"><span>Homepage</span></a></li>
<?php
//select all the top row items
$sql="SELECT * from website_menu where parent_top = '' and parent = '' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    echo '<li';
    if($_GET["id"] == $result["link"])
    {
        echo ' class="active"';
    }
    echo '><a href="/'.$result["link"].'"><span>'.$result["title"].'</span></a>';
    //then select all the next rows down (parent_top)
    $sql2="SELECT * from website_menu where parent_top = '".$result["sequence"]."' ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs2) > 0)
    {
        echo '<ul>';
        while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
        {
            echo '<li><a href="/'.$result2["link"].'"><span>'.$result2["title"].'</span></a>';
            //
            $sql3="SELECT * from website_menu where parent = '".$result2["sequence"]."' ";
            $rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
            if(mysql_num_rows($rs3) > 0)
            {
                echo '<ul>';
                while($result3=mysql_fetch_array($rs3))
                {
                    echo '<li><a href="/'.$result3["link"].'"><span>'.$result3["title"].'</span></a></li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
                echo '</li>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a variable to see if the menu item is selected and put it on false. Set it to false in its main menu loop at the start. Then before printing the menu item to the screen loop over the submenu items, create a string with the submenu and check if one of them is on the current page. If one is the current page set the selected variable to true. After the submenu loop you will have a variable that holds if the menu item should have an additonal class and can you create the item with the submenu.

**Edit**

```
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
   <li <?php if($_GET["id"] == '') { echo 'class="active"'; } ?>><a href="/home.php><span>Homepage</span></a></li>
<?php
//select all the top row items
$sql="SELECT * from website_menu where parent_top = '' and parent = '' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
  //then select all the next rows down (parent_top)
  $current = false;
  $subMenu = '';
  $sql2="SELECT * from website_menu where parent_top = '".$result["sequence"]."' ";
  $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
  if(mysql_num_rows($rs2) > 0)
  {
    $subMenu = '<ul>';
    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
    {
        if($page == $currentPage)
        {
            $current = true;
        }
        $subMenu .= '<li><a href="/'.$result2["link"].'"><span>'.$result2["title"].'</span></a>';
        //
        $sql3="SELECT * from website_menu where parent = '".$result2["sequence"]."' ";
        $rs3=mysql_query($sql3,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($rs3) > 0)
        {
            $subMenu .='<ul>';
            while($result3=mysql_fetch_array($rs3))
            {
                $subMenu .='<li><a href="/'.$result3["link"].'"><span>'.$result3["title"].'</span></a></li>';
            }
            $subMenu .='</ul>';
            $subMenu .='</li>';
        }
        else
        {
            $subMenu .='</li>';
        }
    }
    $subMenu .= '</ul>';
}
    echo '<li';
if($_GET["id"] == $result["link"] || $current)
{
    echo ' class="active"';
}
echo '><a href="/'.$result["link"].'"><span>'.$result["title"].'</span></a>', $subMenu, '</li>';
 }
?>
 </ul>
```

Comment: hmm ok - i kind of understand... any chance you could do a quick example?

Comment: just a small snippet to illustrate the idea

Comment: where do the $page and $currentPage variables come from?

Comment: also, this is making all the <li> elements have a class of active?

Comment: the varibale $page and $currentPage are just some I made up, $page is the page the link points to and $currentPage is the page the user is on. I havn't actualy set anything. This is also the reason all the li are active. Looking at your code I would say $currentPage is $_GET['id'] and $page is $result["link"]

Comment: I have this link structure for one link - Services > Sub 1 > Sub Sub 1
I Sub Sub 1 is selected, the Services link is not active?